# Path is found inside a executable for a particular file

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix, xcode5

We have a app inside which we have the mac executable. When we try to execute strings app_executable | grep User we get a particular file name with the full path as the output. 
This should not happen as it is vulnerable and also it tells the developer's name and the folder structure details. 
Kindly let me know how to avoid this.
The front end code is written in objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that we use NSAssert() in our code which will lead to having the strings present in your executable which might disclose unwanted information about the project. To avoid this we can have NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS in the Project settings under preprocessoor macros for Release mode which will fix this or else we need to make sure the NSAssert is absolutely required if not, we can remove it.

Preprocessor Macros

Release - NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS